# Example of a unital contractive map that is not completely positive on an operator system

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, complete-positivity

I am aware of maps that are positive but not completely positive (for example transpose map). BUT I can not think of an example of the following type.

Does there exist an operator $T$ such that a map $\varphi:\text{span}\{I, T,T^*\}\rightarrow M_n$ is unital contractive on $\text{span}\{I,T,T^*\}$ but NOT completely positive on $\text{span}\{I,T,T^*\}$?

The difficulty of producing such an example occurs because I want a map that is not completely positive on a special kind of operator system, not necessarily on a whole $C^*$-algebra where the operator system is embedded.

Comment: I guess the transpose map on $M_2$ isn't completely positive on some 3-dimensional operator subsystem.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA It will not lead us to the required example as a map on a operator system generated by $2$-by-$2$ matrix is completely positive if and only if it is positive and we know transpose is always positive map. In fact, it is true for any quadratic $T$ shown by TSO and WU..

Comment: Thanks. That's good to know.

Comment: Here is the [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/rocky-mountain-journal-of-mathematics/volume-29/issue-3/Matricial-Ranges-of-Quadratic-Operators/10.1216/rmjm/1181071625.full) for your reference.